# Что правильнее Java Generic Interface и Generic Methods в данном случае?

Tags: java, generics

Данный вопрос возник из-за спо... дискуссии с коллегой, что именно предпочтительнее. Есть код, который можно записать двумя способами:

**1 Способ:**

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    T function(T prm);
}
```

и

**2 Способ:**

```
public interface MyInterface {
    <T> T function(T prm);
}
```

Реализация интерфейса один класс MyInterfaceImpl (так же с Generic у класса или метода), класс создается с помощью `Spring DI` в конструкторах классов, то есть:

**1 Способ:**

```
public class OtherClass {
  private final MyInterface<String> str;

  @Inject
  public OtherClass(MyInterface<String> str) {
     this.str = str;
  }
```

**2 Способ:**

```
public class OtherClass {
  private final MyInterface str;

  @Inject
  public OtherClass(MyInterface str) {
     this.str = str;
  }
```

В принципе сама по себе реализация обоими способами не проблема. Вопрос в правильности, плюсах и минусах каждого подхода. Если сможете приведите цитаты Oracle документации или известных авторов по этому вопросу (я пока не нашел хороших).

**Update**: 
Еще раз о условиях:
1. у интерфейсов и классов только один метод, 
2. в каждом классе, где он используется интерфейс/метод работает только с одним типом,
3. оба варианта использовать в принципе можно.

Answer (score 14):

И так, и так правильно, вы должны смотреть на то, какой *смысл* вашего класса. То есть, вы должны программировать ваши классы так, чтобы *их дизайн соответствовал предметной области*.

Например, если у вас есть универсальный завод по производству оружия, то у вас он один, а типов оружия может производить много:

```
public class WeaponFactory {
    public <T extends Weapon> T produce() { ... }
}
```

А если у вас станок, который выпускает один тип оружия, то этот тип — «параметр» самого станка, и его разновидность выпускаемого оружия предпределена:

```
public class WeaponMachine<T extends Weapon> {
    public T make() { ... }
}
```

Смотрите на семантику ваших классов.

---

У меня нет подтверждающих источников, но я думаю, это и есть один из центральных, обычно не проговариваемых вслух принципов ООП.

У нас есть много вариантов разбить ответственность между различными методами и группами методов. Некоторые из них приводят к проблемам. (Например, ответственность за какие-то действия может по ошибке не достаться никакому из объектов.)

Так вот, идея состоит в следующем: если писать объекты и раздавать полномочия так, что это соответствовало умениям и действиям объектов в реальной жизни (то есть, в *предметной области*), то тут шансов для проблем меньше. Потому что ведь в реальной жизни такая схема работает? Значит и в программе должна работать. А если что-то не получается, мы можем сравнить наш код с «работающей моделью» из реальности, и посмотреть, какой части информации нам не хватает.

Comment: В моем случае, есть только один тип оружия, как я писал выше. Мне скорее нужно найти аргументы, чтобы убедить почему 2 вариант предпочтительнее, каких-то внутренних переменных/других методов нет, класс просто принимает некоторый объект и объект того же типа возвращает.

Comment: Аргумент очень простой: дизайн классов _должен соответствовать предметной области_.

Comment: Вынесу это в ответ.

Answer (score 9):

Если вы хотите чтобы класс который будет наследовать Ваш интерфейс работал только с одним типом тогда `MyInterface<T>` подходит больше, так как крайне не удобно будет использовать дженерик методы если класс будет работать только с одним типом, Вам надо будет каждый раз явно указать тип с помощью `<T>`

Но если вы хотите чтобы класс который будет наследовать Ваш интерфейс работал с разными типами тогда лучше пользоваться дженерик методами.

Хорошим примером будет `java.util.List`. В нем есть методы которые используют тип дженерика (`boolean add(E e);`, `E set(int index, E element);`), и дженерик методы (`<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);`) и и другие.